# Can Armament Haki be used when in Logia form?

Tags: one-piece

When a Logia Devil Fruit eater alters his shape to his type of fruit (like Ace becoming fire), can he cover himself with Armament Haki?

We know that it can be used on the body and weapons, is it usable on the Logia form itself?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. That kind of Haki works independently from Devil Fruit. However, if something is "generated" by Devil Fruit, you can enhance it with Armament Haki.

Answer (score 3):

As [@JustPlain has stated](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/47844/2516), anyone can use the two types of Haki (Observation or Armament) regardless of the fruit type they have or have not eaten.

You can see Smoker using it in his fight against Vergo on Punk Hazard in Chapter 616.

[image]

Comment: @Proxy But as you can see, smoker's hand is in its physical form when he used haki, my question was can he use haki on Smoke for example ? since his body is smoke.

Comment: Oh you mean like, if he can shoot smoke "bubbles" that are clad with haki? If so i would say yes, although out of my head i do not remember if i ever saw an instance of that in the manga, but we saw plenty of examples when different weapons like arrows and swords were infused with haki so i see no reason why logia users would not be able use it on intangible parts of their body.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as you can see, Katakuri is using Haki on his Mochi Mochi devil fruit ability.

[image: Katakuri is using Haki on his Mochi Mochi devil fruit ability]

He coated his mochi ability with haki to give it more of a hardened punch. He is a special Paramecia devil fruit eater, so sorry if this isn't as acceptable. I am sure a Logia type can do the same though using the [examples by @Proxy](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/47867/2516).

He also transforms his right hand into a gun with his Mochi Mochi no Mi, covers it with Haki, and then shoots out mochi bullets.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a logia type can use Armament Haki in logia form. For an example: a logia type user cannot touch anybody in their logia form, so they can use Armament Haki to touch them while the other person can't touch them if they suddenly stop using Haki.

Also if a person is about to use Armament Haki on a Logia, then the Devil Fruit eater can use their own Haki to hit the other person.

This happened when Smoker fought Vergo with Haki